# How should I include the files generated by laravel mix in my scripts and styles?

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, vuejs2

As I run "npm run production" mix generates minified files and saves them in specific directory.
But how can I include them in my scripts and styles as the default name of the file is app.js and the one generated by mix is that it appends some charecter in name.
[image: mix generated app.js vue file]

and in my blade file I have included in following way:
[image]

I am stuck at this as I wanted this inclusion process to be dynamic. Please suggest the approaches in which I can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`mix()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting) helper. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting):

> After generating the versioned file, you won't know the exact file name. So, you should use Laravel's global `mix` function within your views to load the appropriately hashed asset. The `mix` function will automatically determine the current name of the hashed file:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/frontend/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I never realized that there is such a simple solution to this problem.